How to implement circuit breaker with Resilience4j in a Spring Boot project with multiple databases
I'm facing an issue with my Spring Boot project that involves three different databases. I've set up datasources and JPA configurations to map the repositories to their respective databases. I'm attaching an example of my class code. My goal is to implement a circuit breaker with Resilience4j to handle database failures. Specifically, I need the application to continue functioning if any of the databases fail. Additionally, one of the databases is currently inactive and undergoing maintenance. However, its unavailability prevents me from starting the project due to connection errors. Is it possible to configure the circuit breaker to manage connection errors at the application startup and allow the project to start?
@Configuration("colDataSourcesConfig")
public class DataSourcesConfig {

    // obtiene las propiedades de la base de datos
    @Bean("oracleColProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.oraclecol")
    public DataSourceProperties getOracleColProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    // obtiene el origen de datos de la base de datos
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("oracleColDataSource")
    public DataSource getOracleColoDataSource(){
        return getOracleColProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }
// crea un cliente jdbc para la base de datos usando el origen de datos
    @Bean
    public JdbcClient jdbcClientCol (@Qualifier("oracleColDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return JdbcClient.create(dataSource);
    }



@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.femsa.oxxo.repository.utileriarepository.col",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "oracleColEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "oracleColTransactionManager"
)

@EnableTransactionManagement
public class OracleColJpaConfig {

    @Bean("oracleColEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oracleColEntityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("oracleColDataSource" ) DataSource oracleColDataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(oracleColDataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.femsa.oxxo.model");
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("oracleCol");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Map<String,String> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>();
        //additionalProperties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        //additionalProperties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(additionalProperties);
        return em;
    }

    @Bean("oracleColTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager getOracleColTransactionManager(@Qualifier("oracleColEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oracleColEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(oracleColEntityManagerFactory.getObject()));
    }

}

What I've Tried:
I've explored various configurations and approaches within Spring Boot, but I haven't found a solution yet. I've considered implementing Resilience4j's circuit breaker functionality, but I'm unsure about its integration with multiple datasources in a Spring Boot environment. Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
